# Create a C Project in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw

I have installed Eclipse Kepler C++ IDE. I have also configured MinGW for windows and Eclipse Kepler for MinGW. I have created one project named 'AsteriskGraph'. I have to type the following code so please guide me how to create or change the architecture.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,rows
    printf("Enter no of rows"); 
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=1;j++)
        {
           printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }  
}
```

Comment: First you have to create a class, (File > new > Source File). The name have to end with '.c'

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a project (File-->New-->C Project); the project wizard is simple to follow; the main source file is also created with the project, and you can input the code into it. If you need more source files, then you need to create the source file for each (File-->New-->"Source File" or "Header File").